# Spring integration inbound jms adapter error-channel does not invoke

Tags: spring, jms, integration

The scenario is inbound jms adapter -> service activators (db search, business logic, inserts or updates)

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="swiftAdapterInput" channel="mt950"
        connection-factory="connectionFactory" destination-name="${integration.swift.jms.queue.from}" pub-sub-domain="false"
        auto-startup="false" error-channel="errorChannel" transaction-manager="transactionManager" acknowledge="transacted" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel" ref="errorHandler" />

<bean id="errorHandler" class="nest.integration.utils.error.ErrorHandler" />


<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

When the exception was thrown during my servcie activators my errorHandler works fine but  the exception was at the end(after commit), for example db unique constrat exception the message does not go to error-channel but rollbacked to jms queue only.

But I need my errorHander in this case also because I need to send email exception etc.

Tanks at advance
Best wishes, Tamas

Comment: What is the Exception you get?

Comment: Please turn on DEBUG for the `org.springframework.integration` category and show here logs on the matter

Comment: The debug was active. No debug message about error-channel.

Comment: WARN  MessageListenerContainer#1-7 org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'Consumer.Lime.VirtualTopic.SWIFT.Interface.Test1' - trying to recover. Cause: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00001: a(z) (NEST.LIME_MT950_DETAIL_PK) egyediségre vonatkozó megszorítás nem tel

Comment: The exception is ok pk unique constarit, but I want to handle this in errorHandler to send a email etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue that you must rallback TX in your `errorHandler`, but don't commit.

That's why you get `egyediségre vonatkozó megszorítás nem tel` from `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`, because that DB error is caused on commit.

See here: [Exceptions in Spring Integration: How to log but not intercept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25566934/exceptions-in-spring-integration-how-to-log-but-not-intercept/25569008#25569008)

Comment: Spring commit the transaction at the end not me. The problem is that my error handler is not invoked.

Comment: > When the exception was thrown during my servcie activators my errorHandler works fine

Comment: Your words. So, or you must rethrow exception from your `errorChannel` or just rallback it manually. That's true that Spring tries to commit TX, but it can't because of constraint issue. And the constraint is the result of that exception from service activator.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that is another exception what my service activator throws for example checking some business check and throw custom exception if nessesary. In this case my errorHander gets the message and I can send email etc. But when dao.save and has db pk constrait exception my errorHandler has not got any message but rollbacked to queue. Sorry for my bad english :-(

Comment: Please, swith on DEBUG for the `org.springframework.jms.listener` category to the StackTrace from `handleListenerSetupFailure`.

Comment: I switched on, no handleListenerSetupFailure int the log.

Comment: only this:[2014-09-04 11:59:34.107] WARN  MessageListenerContainer#0-7 org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'Consumer.Lime.VirtualTopic.SWIFT.Interface.Test1' - trying to recover. Cause: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] 
(Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00001: a(z) (NEST.LIME_MT950_DET

Comment: The enviroment: Eclipse virgo 3.6 apps server, Spring 3.1.3.RELEASE, Spring integration 2.2.1.RELEASE

Comment: Yes, I understand that it is a `DatabaseException`, but I need to know the call stack from the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`. The idea if we can provide our own `errorHandler` to the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`. The `error-channel` isn't reachable here already, because your Integration flow has been finished already and you really can't send compensation message from there. Another idea to use NESTED transaction for the `service-activator`, when the commit (with potential rollback on DB constraint). In this case `error-channel` is still there.

Comment: I tried nested, but oracle 11g not supported this? Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.NestedTransactionNotSupportedException: JpaDialect does not support savepoints - check your JPA provider's capabilities

Comment: OK. Would it be good for your use-case, if you district JMS and JPA transactions? I mean place between your SI components `queue-channel`, when JMS TX will be commited just after receiving message.

Comment: I would like to handle in one transaction if db failed robback to queue but send email about error.